# Capture Raw NIC IO from .NET Socket as a .NET BitArray

Tags: .net, sockets, io

I want to master certain raw protocols to learn about TCP Stream resuming.

I am versed in .Net sockets, and would like to initiate a TCP stream so:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(Tcp)
socket.connect(IPAddress);
socket.send(new byte[]{155});
socket.close();
```

Then be able to read the raw IO network card data sent/recieved and save it as

```
BitArray sentData;
BitArray recievedData;
```

Hope I can :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) or the [.NET bindings](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/) for it to capture/send raw network packets